Canvas Drawing Mask Not Accurately Captured in HTML5 and JavaScript for Image Inpainting
I'm working on an image inpainting application where users can paint over areas they want to remove on a canvas. The drawn mask should then be sent to the server for processing. However, I'm encountering an issue where the generated mask doesn't match the drawn area accurately, resulting in poor inpainting results.
Here's what I've done so far:
HTML Structure:
Here's what I've done so far:
HTML Structure:
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Inpaint Image</title>
    <style>
        /* Styles omitted for brevity */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Paint on the object you want to remove</h1>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
        <button id="undoButton" disabled>Undo</button>
        <form id="maskForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="maskData" id="maskData">
            <input type="hidden" name="filename" id="filename" value="{{ filename }}">
            <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="submitMask();" id="removeButton">
        </form>
        <label for="brushSize">Brush Size:</label>
        <input type="range" id="brushSize" name="brushSize" min="1" max="50" value="5">
        <button id="downloadButton" style="display:none;">Download Image</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = `/static/uploads/{{ filename }}`;
        const undoButton = document.getElementById('undoButton');
        let undoStack = [];
        let mask = [];
        let brushSize = 5;  // Default brush size

        img.onload = () => {
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            mask = new Uint8Array(canvas.width * canvas.height).fill(0);
            saveState();
        };

        let drawing = false;

        function saveState() {
            undoStack.push(canvas.toDataURL());
            undoButton.disabled = false;
        }

        function restoreState() {
            if (undoStack.length > 0) {
                const state = undoStack.pop();
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = state;
                img.onload = () => {
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    for (let i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
                        mask[i / 4] = imgData.data[i] === 255 ? 255 : 0;
                    }
                };
            }
            if (undoStack.length === 0) {
                undoButton.disabled = true;
            }
        }

        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
            drawing = true;
            saveState();
        });

        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
            drawing = false;
        });

        canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
            if (drawing) {
                drawing = false;
            }
        });

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
            if (!drawing) return;
            const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
            const y = e.clientY - rect.top;
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)';
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(x, y, brushSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.fill();
            updateMask(x, y, brushSize);
        });

        document.getElementById('brushSize').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
            brushSize = parseInt(e.target.value);
        });

        function updateMask(x, y, brushSize) {
            const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            const scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width;
            const scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height;
            const scaledX = Math.floor(x * scaleX);
            const scaledY = Math.floor(y * scaleY);
            const brushRadius = Math.floor(brushSize * scaleX / 2);

            for (let i = -brushRadius; i <= brushRadius; i++) {
                for (let j = -brushRadius; j <= brushRadius; j++) {
                    const dist = Math.sqrt(i * i + j * j);
                    if (dist <= brushRadius) {
                        const maskX = scaledX + i;
                        const maskY = scaledY + j;
                        if (maskX >= 0 && maskX < canvas.width && maskY >= 0 && maskY < canvas.height) {
                            mask[maskY * canvas.width + maskX] = 255;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function submitMask() {
            const maskData = Array.from(mask).join(',');
            const filename = document.getElementById('filename').value;
            canvas.classList.add('blinking');
            fetch('/inpaint_ajax', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ maskData, filename }),
            })
            .then(response => response.blob())
            .then(blob => {
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                img.src = url;
                img.onload = () => {
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                    canvas.width = img.width;
                    canvas.height = img.height;
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    mask = new Uint8Array(canvas.width * canvas.height).fill(0);
                    canvas.classList.remove('blinking');
                    document.getElementById('downloadButton').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('downloadButton').onclick = () => downloadImage(url);
                };
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
        }

        function downloadImage(url) {
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'processed_image.png';
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            document.body.removeChild(a);
        }

        undoButton.addEventListener('click', restoreState);
    </script>
</body>
</html>



Backend Processing (Flask):
`@app.route('/inpaint_ajax', methods=['POST'])
 def inpaint_ajax():
   data = request.get_json()
   filename = data['filename']
   mask_data = data['maskData']

   image_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
   img = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')
   original_size = img.size

  fixed_size = app.config['FIXED_SIZE']

  image_tensor = preprocess_image(image_path, fixed_size)
  mask_tensor = preprocess_mask(mask_data, original_size[::-1], fixed_size)

  lama_model = load_lama_model(app.config['MODEL_PATH'])
  with torch.no_grad():
      inpainted_tensor = lama_model(image_tensor, mask_tensor)

  output_path = os.path.join(app.config['OUTPUT_FOLDER'], filename)
  postprocess_and_save(inpainted_tensor, output_path, original_size)

  shutil.copy(output_path, image_path)

  mask_array = np.array(mask_data.split(','), dtype=np.uint8).reshape(original_size[::-1])
  mask_image_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f'mask_{filename}')
  cv2.imwrite(mask_image_path, mask_array)

  return send_from_directory(app.config['OUTPUT_FOLDER'], filename)

`
Despite implementing the above code, the mask generated on the server doesn't match the area drawn by the user. The mask seems to miss parts or doesn't align with the brush strokes accurately.
  

Can you explain why the brush size used in creating the mask is a function of scaleX and not scaleY, or are they the same?

The brush size used in creating the mask can be a function of either scaleX or scaleY depending on the aspect ratio and scaling of the canvas. Typically, they are the same if the canvas is uniformly scaled. However, in cases where the canvas is scaled differently along the width and height, using both scaleX and scaleY ensures accurate mapping. For consistent results, it's best to consider both or use an average to maintain uniform brush size across different scaling factors.

So, that’s my question, why is only scaleX used in calculating brush radius when working out the mask? I ask not just because that seems strange, but because the resulting mask you are getting looks as though the radius could be incorrect (too small).

Thank you so much for pointing out the importance of using both scaleX and scaleY in calculating the brush radius for the mask. Your insight helped me realize the need for a more accurate approach, and now the mask generation is working perfectly. I truly appreciate your valuable hint!

By incorporating both scaling factors, the mask generation now accurately reflects the drawn area.
function updateMask(x, y, brushSize) {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width;
  const scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height;


  const brushRadius = Math.floor((brushSize * scaleX + brushSize * scaleY) / 2);

  const startX = Math.max(0, Math.floor((x - brushRadius) * scaleX));
  const startY = Math.max(0, Math.floor((y - brushRadius) * scaleY));
  const endX = Math.min(canvas.width, Math.ceil((x + brushRadius) * scaleX));
  const endY = Math.min(canvas.height, Math.ceil((y + brushRadius) * scaleY));

  for (let i = startX; i < endX; i++) {
      for (let j = startY; j < endY; j++) {
          const dx = i / scaleX - x;
          const dy = j / scaleY - y;
          if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= brushRadius) {
              mask[j * canvas.width + i] = 255;
          }
      }
  }
}

